# Django no lee el script luego de heredar una plantilla y usar el {%block content%}

Tags: python, django

```
Estos son los códigos:
```

archivo 1
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

archivo 2:
[image: imagen]

en el archivo numero 2 el script que va entre el {%block content%} y {%end block%} no funciona.

¿Qué podría hacer para resolver este problema? He intentado usar Chatgpt para resolver esto más sin embargo no funciona nada.

Comment: El código siempre _como texto, con formato_. [No todos pueden ver las imágenes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976). Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0):

Trata de separar el contenido dentro de los templates tags.

Por ejemplo tienes: `{%block content%}` pásalo a **`{% block content %}`** lo mismo con `{%extends 'navigation_bar.html'%}`, hay veces que eso da error al tenerlo pegado.